# Windows 7 исчезает память виртуальная и RAM

Tags: windows-7

Начала исчезать виртуальная память, т.е. постепенно, равномерно иссякать(на скрине). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

-В настройках размера виртуальной пам. стоят "По умолчанию", хотя и пробовал расширять.

-С помощью RamMap понял, что постоянно расширяется Page Table из-за того, что регулярно создаются процесы cmd.exe и conhost.exe, которые занимают по 20к в Page Table(проверил комп ESETом - ничего).

-Так же c помощью Process Explorer замечаю, что процессы создаются на мгновение ока, а потом удаляются сразу же(в описании процесса 0 информации, только PID и сколько занимает), но в Page Table остаются все так же.

-Malwarebytes ничего не нашел.

-Читал, что у кого-то была проблема и помогло обновление драйверов. Обновил драйвера с помощью DriverPack

Как я могу узнать что создает эти процессы? Или как убить это действие без вреда системе?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте все списки автозагрузки (ключи в реестре Run и т.п.). Можно с помощью специальных сторонних программ. Или может вам стоит обновить антивирус, у вас какой кстати?

Comment: спасибо за ответ! ESET(лицензия, если это имеет значение). Проверил каждый ключ в реестре Run для пользователя и машины, не нашел ничего необычногою. Предпологаю, что проблема кроется не во вредоносном ПО, ибо Malwarebytes вместе с антивирусом что-то да показали бы, но я не уверен на 100%